# How can I set a domain hint for a multi-tenant Azure AD request?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

When using Azure AD for authentication using OpenID Connect, it is possible to include a `domain_hint` parameter in the authentication request to redirect the user to their branded Azure login page (similar to using `whr` - see the difference between http://login.microsoftonline.com/ and http://login.microsoftonline.com?whr=microsoft.com, for example).

If providing services for a single tenant, it is easy enough to set this up using something like:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = authority,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
        {
            RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) => 
            {                                                        
                context.ProtocolMessage.DomainHint = "mydomain.com"; 
                return Task.FromResult(0); 
            }, 
        }
    })
```

However, I am working on a multi-tenant application which asks for the user's email, and then depending on configuration settings, will either allow the user to log on using a local password, or will redirect them to Azure for authentication.  This is effected by a call to:

```
context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, "AzureAd");
```

Since I do not know the `DomainHint` at app startup (and it will change depending on the user's organisation), is there a way to pass the `DomainHint` parameter as part of the `Challenge` method's properties or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soon after I asked the question I started down a similar route to the answer posted by @vibronet, and for those who come after the solution is posted here.

Part of the `properties` object (of type `AuthenticationProperties`) in the call to `Challenge()` above is a `Dictionary<string, string>` object, called `Dictionary` (as luck would have it).  Before the `Challenge()` call, the domain hint was set on this:

```
properties.Dictionary["DomainHint"] = domainHint;
```

As @vibronet suggested, it is then possible to access the pipeline through changes to the `app.UserOpenIdConnectAuthentication()` call in Startup.  This call now looks like:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ...
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            ...
            RedirectToIdentityProvider = notification =>
            {
                var dict = notification.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseChallenge.Properties.Dictionary;
                if (dict.ContainsKey("DomainHint"))
                {
                    notification.ProtocolMessage.DomainHint = dict["DomainHint"];
                }

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! Please see http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2017/03/20/tweak-sign-in-messages-with-the-asp-net-owin-middleware/ for a way of passing context from your app to the sign in message building pipeline. You can easily adapt the example (which signals a binary consent option) to specifying domain hint, login hint or any combination you need.